# My images wont stay on the same line, trying to use bootstrap row

Tags: bootstrap-5

My images wont stay on the same row once i put the `<p>` in, they both sit in there own row, not sure what im doing wrong here

```
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="image-fluid text-center">
                <img class="bruno" src="resourcesnew/css/Img/bruno.jpg">
                <p class="h6">Bruno</p>
                <img class="anth" src="resourcesnew/css/Img/anth.jpg">
                <p class="h6">Anthony</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `<p>` is a block level element, they are by default under each other. Why would you expect them to be next to each other?

Comment: So if I wanted the images with the names underneath each one, how would I set that out?

Answer (score 0):

I think whatever CSS you used in `class="row"` is not acting the way you expect, because that div has a single child.

I don't know what's in your css file, but the following HTML works as I expect you want:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="image-fluid text-center" style="display:flex">
        <div>
            <img class="bruno" src="resourcesnew/css/Img/bruno.jpg">
            <p class="h6">Bruno</p>    
        </div>
        <div>
            <img class="anth" src="resourcesnew/css/Img/anth.jpg">
            <p class="h6">Anthony</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each image/text pair gets its own div, and what used to be your `row` div now has multiple children.